# Why closing event not working after resuming wpf application from system tray?

Tags: c#, wpf

My problem is,  I  am hiding my app in system tray when close event is fired, 
User can resume it by double clicking on notify icon. Close event only works for the first time in my wpf app.

```
private void SparkWindow_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {  
           DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to close application?","Confirmation",MessageBoxButton.YesNo,MessageBoxIcon.Question);
            if(dr==DialogResult.No)
            {
            e.Cancel = true;
            this.Hide();                
            notifyIcon.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            }
            else
            {
                  Application.Current.ShutDown();
            }
    }
```

this is how i handle the closing event.

and below given code is used to bring it back in front of from system tray.

```
  private void OnNotifyIconDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
        {
            this.Show();
            this.WindowState = this.lastWindowState;
            this.WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
        }
    }
```

but when it resumes it doesn't fire the closing event 2nd time.

Comment: Other way to do this is to add a icon and then get its event and make window borderless and add a border. but how to do it with the Window close icon event.